# Why are begin() functions needed to initialize hardware (if they are)?

Tags: programming

I'm writing a program for an ATmega microcontroller using the Arduino framework.
While implementing an hardware-related class (one to manage LEDs), I put some hardware initialization code such as `pinMode(OUTPUT)` in the class constructor. Then I realized that in all Arduino libraries I know the hardware initialization is done in a `begin()` or `init()`, so I created one for my Led class as well and moved `pinMode()` there.

Now I'm wondering if I really should define such initialization funcitons, i.e. why they are needed - or, if they are not, why so many libraries have them. I played around a bit and found that for example this code works on an ATmega1284 (it makes the LED on pin 28 light up).

```cpp
struct Test {
  Test() {
    pinMode(28, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(28, HIGH);
    // other stuff
  }
  // ...
};

Test test;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

I presume that this code is somehow ill-conceived, letting alone the fact that it lights up a led without any code in the main function (or maybe that is exaclty the problem?), but if so I can not see why. What did I not consider?
Should the code above be rather writte as in the following snippet, as the existence of all these `begin()` functions leads me to believe?

```cpp
struct Test {
  Test() {
    // other stuff
  }
  void begin() {
    pinMode(28, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(28, HIGH);
  }
  // ...
};

Test test;

void setup() {
  test.begin();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Although Arduino [API styleguide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/APIStyleGuide) recommends to use `begin()` to set thing up. To me both are works and is a design consideration, provided that you know what have been configured and initialised by the `Arduino.h` and [variants](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/variants) for a particular boards, and what you are trying to do in the construct will not be overrided by the `init()` within the Arduino Core `main()`. For example, you see many library use the construct to set thing up like `LCD lcd(SDL, SDA);`.

Comment: To your question about setup() and loop(), see the source code of Arduino Core [main.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp) for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all to do with the order of execution.

Constructors are executed before normal functions. That includes the `main()` function which eventually calls `setup()` and (repeatedly) `loop()`. One of the other things that `main()` does is call `init()` (or some variant of) which configures the hardware.

Since that happens *after* any global constructors have been run anything that the constructor did to the hardware could potentially be undone.

Thus it is normal to defer any hardware configuration until *after* `main()` has done the work of setting things up, and the convention is to use a `begin()` function to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And what is actually this `init()` function? Where is it defined? And, by the way, where is the `main()` function in an Arduino project?

Comment: It's all in the core. Read the cores source code.